# How can I store a lot of data locally for a program

Tags: c#, database

I am current building (in C#) a fairly basic point-of-sale program for a local community in Uganda to use in tracking business at their sunflower seed press. I was thinking that I would need some sort of database (like a SQL database), but I've never set up a database before, so I'm wondering what the best way to do this is. Maybe a database isn't the best way. The program will not have internet access, so everything will have to be done locally on the machine.

Comment: There are open source PoS applications. I suggest you spend some time looking at those before building anything if you just need simple functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I think your first step should be designing out what data you need to store. Build an [Entity Relationship Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_relationship_model) and decide what your domain model is going to be. There are many different Database Engines out there that you can use that have different features, installation requirements, etc. A database engine can be installed locally, or on a remote machine to connect to. If you're writing a C# app, you'll probably want to use the [System.Data namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.aspx). You can use plain ADO .NET, or use something like Linq To Enttiies to help create proxy classes for your data tables.

You can access a SQL database using the same API for queries / record extraction regardless of the DB Engine uses. In some caess, you may need to use a seperate library that provides an implementation (or a better one), as in the case of an Oracle Database and the Oracle Data Access Components. Right out of the gate, .NET works very well with Microsoft SQL Server, but other options would work.

The details of what database engine are not as important as defining a good set of data tables to represent your data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If it has lots of data you have to consider using database. Whether you have internet or not, as long as you have local network, you can easily do database.

1. Set up a database server ( maybe sql)
2. Do your database and install it on the database server
3. Do your application and connect to your database through connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track to use a database to store data. It is pretty easy to accomplish. Your computer does not need to be connected to the internet.

[SQL Server Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/database/free-database.aspx) is free with a limit of 10 gigs of data. This will probably be much, much more space than you will need.

From C#, use ADO.NET.  It is very simple if you know some SQL.  Code samples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090.aspx).